# SQL Pivot tables and counts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pivot-table

Ok I've created a `SystemUser` and `Organisation` tables with a `UserOrganisation` pivot table but my issue is I want to display in a kendo grid a user count of how many users per Organisation.

I would usually do something like have a permission table and do the below,

```
var UserCount = _db.Permissions
                   .Where(w => w.OrganisationId == Organisations.Id)
                   .Count();
```

Of course since my `.edmx` doesn't have the Pivot table I can't do `_db.UserOrganisations.Where`

I've tried doing a bit of googling to come up with an answer but either I'm thinking about this incorrectly or the answer's staring me right in the face and I just don't see it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your `Organisation` entity class have a `Users` property ?

Comment: @Shyju yes and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dbContext has a `Organisations` property which lists a collection of Organisation objects and your `Organisation` entity has a `Users` Property which stores the organization members.

```
var orgList= db.Organisations.Select(s => new 
                     { Name = s.Name, MemberCount = s.Users.Count() }).ToList();
```

This will list a list of **anonymous** type with a `Name` and `MemberCount` property. But, If you want a list of viewmodels, do this

```
var orgList= db.Organisations.Select(s => new OrganizationVM 
                   { Name = s.Name, MemberCount = s.Users.Count() }).ToList();
```

Assuming your `OrganizationVM` has a `Name` and `MemberCount` property

```
public class OrganizationVM 
{
  public string Name { set;get; }
  public int MemberCount { set;get; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was meaning but it did alert me to the next issue I'd have. var UserCount = (from o in _db.OrganisationalUnits
                             where o.Id == organisation.Id
                             from t in o.SystemUsers
                             select t).Count();  This is what I'd want but in the same syntax as in my question or your answer but from your answer it made me think about the next stage of display a user list for a particular organisation which I think I'd either be able to figure out with the correct syntax or at least know the right question.

Comment: By my understanding your answer would provide me with a list of organisation names and the user count for each, this is almost what I'm using in a kendo grid as it displays all child organisations then has a column which shows the user count. That column would be a button redirecting to a user list which is where I'd then want to display all users for a particular organisation.

Comment: Yes. It will return name and the user count. If you want to show it in a button, that is something you need to adjust in your UI/View.

Comment: This would give me an alternative simple display which I could use but I was wondering if it was possible to get a list of all users as that would allow me to use the same approach to display all the users in a list and pass each record into a VM/DTO to add information where it's needed?

Comment: I found something similar to this which I was able to change to meet my requirements but I'd still prefer to use the other syntax, var UserCount = (from o in _db.Organisation
                             where o.Id == organisation.Id
                             from t in o.SystemUsers
                             select t).Count();

Comment: Is this the only syntax I can use shyju or do you know if I can perform the same query using my question example syntax?

Comment: Shyju is there some reason why you are no longer responding?

Comment: @Myzifer My answer will cover the question you posted originally. I am not sure what else you are looking for now. Also if you have a different question, **DO NOT ASK THAT IN COMMENTS**. Please post a new question with relevant information.

Comment: Actually my question wasn't to have a list with the organisation and there count but to instead find the count of an organisation as I already had the organisation list, your answer did not cover my original question which is why I'd kept asking things in comments. Yes I did ask for additional information not directly related to my question but ignoring that is not the best method of communicating to me you want me to ask it in a new question.